# Can't word wrap on vs code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

I have tried almost everything but could not figure out how could i remove the horizontal scrollbar from my vs code i have changed every setting but could not figure out how to on my word wrap on vs code. At first it worked but suddenly it stopped working a month before could not figure out what could be the reason maybe some extension. Any help would be appreciated.
Following is code for my setting.json and screen shot of my settings and the horizontal scroll bar.

```
{
"editor.mouseWheelZoom": true,
"code-runner.runInTerminal": true,
"liveServer.settings.donotShowInfoMsg": true,
"C_Cpp.updateChannel": "Insiders",
"code-runner.saveFileBeforeRun": true,
"editor.formatOnPaste": true,
"editor.formatOnSave": true,
"editor.formatOnType": true,
"debug.terminal.clearBeforeReusing": true,
"code-runner.clearPreviousOutput": true,
"latex-workshop.view.pdf.viewer": "browser",
"workbench.colorTheme": "Visual Studio Dark",
"workbench.iconTheme": "vscode-icons",
"diffEditor.wordWrap": "on",
"emmet.triggerExpansionOnTab": true,
"editor.accessibilitySupport": "on",
"bracket-pair-colorizer-2.depreciation-notice": false,
"editor.wrappingColumn": 0,
"kite.showWelcomeNotificationOnStartup": false,
"terminal.integrated.profiles.windows": {
    "PowerShell": {
        "source": "PowerShell",
        "icon": "terminal-powershell"
    },
    "Command Prompt": {
        "path": [
            "${env:windir}\\Sysnative\\cmd.exe",
            "${env:windir}\\System32\\cmd.exe"
        ],
        "args": [],
        "icon": "terminal-cmd"
    },
    "Git Bash": {
        "source": "Git Bash"
    },
    "Ubuntu-18.04 (WSL)": {
        "path": "C:\\WINDOWS\\System32\\wsl.exe",
        "args": [
            "-d",
            "Ubuntu-18.04"
        ]
    }
},
"terminal.integrated.defaultProfile.windows": "PowerShell",
"security.workspace.trust.untrustedFiles": "open",
"[html]": {
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "vscode.html-language-features"
},
"files.associations": {
    "*.css": "css"
},
"[css]": {
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "vscode.css-language-features"
},
"workbench.startupEditor": "none",
"editor.wordWrap": "on"
```

}
[image: screen shot of horizontal bar]
[image: screenshot of my settings]

Answer (score 0):

Q: You'd like to see word wrap in the editor window, as you're editing an HTML file in VSCode, correct?

Q: And you *DON'T* want the editor to insert line breaks in the actual HTML - you just don't want to have to scroll left and right.  Correct?

Q: Have you tried `Alt-Z`?  Or `View > Toggle word wrap`?

NOTE: be sure the HTML editor pane is "Selected" when you try "Alt-Z".

Comment: yes i have tried everything and i just don't want to have to scroll left and right and i have tried toggle word wrap